# The named parameter 'child' isn't defined. Error Flutter 2.5.1

Tags: flutter, dart

Today I updated my flutter version to 2.5.1 and I got the error `The named parameter 'child' isn't defined. Try correcting the name to an existing named parameter's name, or defining a named parameter with the name 'child'.` I cleaned the cache, reinstalled flutter, android studio.. The screenshot shows that the `Container` does not have `child`. How do I fix this? Thanks!
[image]
[image]

Comment: Please finish writing code and share your snippet. And did you edit the source code?

Comment: Hello @YeasinSheikh. I created a new project and checked on it. Same

Answer (score -2):

the container does not have any child u must replace it by children

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).